# Yii2: Assigning dynamic properties to model and displaying them in a grid

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

To keep things short, the application itself is really simple, having only three tables.

**Product:**

```
id
name
```

**Attribute**

```
id
name
slug
```

**Product Attribute**

```
id
attribute_id
product_id
value
```

As you may guess the attributes may be totally random, with any content and there might be any number of them. Every product has the same set of global attributes assigned. Some are empty, some are filled.

What I want to do is displaying them in a standard Gridview, the same way as if it was a normal model, with dynamic-preassigned columns and values. Basically speaking - the attributes should serve as the columns.

I've tried to extend the main Product Model and use ActiveDataProvider class on it, but no avail, I'm getting the custom attributes values repeated for each row, as if something was missing. Here's the class I've created basing on another question from SO.

```
namespace common\models;

use Yii;
use common\models\Attribute;
use common\models\Product;

class ProductDynamic extends Product {


public function init() {
    parent::init();
    $attrExists = ProductAttribute::find()->select(['slug','value'])->joinWith(['attributeModel'])->all();
    if ($attrExists) {
        foreach ($attrExists as $at) {
            $this->dynamicFields[$at['slug']] = $at['value'];
        }
    }
}

private $dynamicFields = [];

public function __get($name) {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->dynamicFields))
        return $this->dynamicFields[$name];
    else
    return parent::__get($name);
}

public function __set($name, $value) {
    if (array_key_exists($name, $this->dynamicFields))
        $this->dynamicFields[$name] = $value;
    else
        parent::__set($name, $value);
}

public function rules() {
    return array_merge(parent::rules, $this->dynamicRules);
}

}
```

My question is - how would you do it? How to assign properties to a model so they act as a standard database-loaded properties usable by ActiveDataProvider? I think I need to retrieve the ProductAttributes some other way so they are not repeated. See below.

[image: The names are correct but the parameters are all wrong]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering it myself since there's no feedback and after some more digging i've found the quickest, but maybe not the nicest solution.

Since the properties in main Product model are added thanks to the ProductDynamic class I have added the following in Product to assign correct column values. For sure, there must be another, easier way, if you know any feel free to comment.

```
public function afterFind() {
    $attrs = ProductAttribute::find()->select(['slug', 'value'])->joinWith(['attributeModel'])->where(['product_id' => $this->id])->all();

    foreach ($attrs as $a) {
        $this->{$a['slug']} = $a['value'];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i think i got your idea...

So, I think you could  generate an attribute in the model of Product (we will call it ProductAttributeArr) which would be an array, then retrieve the attributes from the  Attribute table in the database according to Product Attribute table and store them in ProductAttributeArr.

Then you could create a function that dynamically generates the parameters for the GridView base on the content of ProductAttributeArr. This way it should work.